# IF Statement simplification

Tags: php, if-statement

How does one achieve multiple checks against one value? I think I'm being a little bit stupid...

What I want to achieve is this:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != ("1.php" || "2.php" || "3.php"){
    header('Location: elsewhere.php'); 
}
```

rather than:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != "1.php" && basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != "2.php" && basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != "3.php" && basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != "4.php"){
    header('Location: elsewhere.php'); 
}
```

I've written it out a few times but I'm clearly licking windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: put it inside an array, then put `in_array()` inside the if

Answer (score 4):

you can write

```
$files = array("1.php", "2.php", "3.php", "4.php");//so on

if(!in_array(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), $files)){
    header('Location: elsewhere.php'); 
}
```

yes another method is (little bit faster than above one)

```
if(array_diff((array)(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])),array("1.php", "2.php", "3.php", "4.php")))
{
 header('Location: elsewhere.php'); 
}
```

Comment: Logic should be reversed to not in array.

Comment: I like this, very simple and I should have thought it it myself - thank you. I'm very keen to see alternatives if there are any? I'll mark this as my answer when I'm permitted to do so.